# sonar report with 0 bugs and vulnerabilities

Tags: swift, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I had a very strange problem when using sonar with my swift project. Although, I get usually 0 bugs and 0 vulnerabilities every statics have 0 values which really very strange. this my report:
[image: Sonar report]
I had installed SwiftLint, OcLint and Xcpretty recording to the documentation below:
[Link sonar swift](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift)
This sonar-project.properties structure:

```
sonar.projectKey=testSonar
sonar.projectName=testSonar
sonar.project=TestSonar.xcodeproj
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
sonar.language=swift
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=latest
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.junit.reportsPath=sonar-reports/
sonar.swift.lizard.report=sonar-reports/lizard-report.xml
sonar.swift.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/coverage-swift*.xml
sonar.swift.swiftlint.report=sonar-reports/*swiftlint.txt
```

I also added the plugin for the swift version like so :
[image: Plugin Swift SonarQube]

To scan I installed using brew the sonarScanner. Finally, I run this command `sonar-scanner` so It launch the scan and It work fine but no errors despite I made error like this:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
   let var x = 3
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Any help please ??

Comment: I am also facing same issue, But for me duplications showing, Are you using Developer Edition or Community Edition for iOS? Because I also got stuck with same issue from past 5 days. Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by using run-sonar-swift.sh and updating my properties file like this:

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
sonar.projectKey=testSonar
sonar.projectName=testSonar
sonar.language=swift
sonar.sources=.
sonar.test.inclusions=*.swift
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*
# Scheme to build your application
sonar.swift.appScheme=TestSonar
sonar.swift.appConfiguration=Debug
```

you need also to download this run-sonar-swift sh file
[run-sonar-swift](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TySvmMrCGfgx8f-PYvtQQpR4AdRxk83h/view?usp=sharing)